# Unable to login to MySQL

Tags: mysql, installation, root

I installed MySQL using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

It asks me for a root password (On package configuration), I enter one and confirm it.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

However when I try logging in to mysql with user root and password which I supplied in the previous step, it denies me access:

```
root@mbilwebh02:/etc# > mysql --user root --password
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

Another attempt that I made was to uninstall and reinstall mysql without supplying a password but that fails as well.

I then switched the user on the server to mysql

```
root@mbilwebh02:/etc# sudo -u mysql -s
root@mbilwebh02:/etc# sudo -u mysql -s
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
mysql@mbilwebh02:/etc$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

At this point I am able to only start and stop mysql. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

[EDIT]

After searching a lot I found that one can log in to mysql using debian-sys-maint as user and password which is in the debian.cnf file. There was no 'root' user in the mysql database hence everything I tried denied me access. 
I do not know if this is a safe way to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

```
Stop mysqld and restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges. Because this is insecure, you might want to use --skip-grant-tables in conjunction with --skip-networking to prevent remote clients from connecting.

Connect to the mysqld server with this command:

shell> mysql

Issue the following statements in the mysql client. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
    ->                   WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

The FLUSH statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change.
```

You should now be able to connect to the MySQL server as root using the new password. Stop the server, then restart it normally (without the --skip-grant-tables and --skip-networking options).